# Error propagation and averaging

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

How is a value for *x* reported in the following example:

*x=by*

*b* has some error *Δb* and is constant,
*y* is a measurable quantity with some error *Δy*

In the case that 5 measurements were taken for *y* (all with the same error but different value), how do we report a value (with error) for *x*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to run in to problems because using the same $b$, which has an uncertainty, for all of the measurements will introduce correlated errors into the average of $x$. So, if you just average your $x$ values and apply standard formulae blindly, you'll underestimate your error in the average. It's better in cases like this to average the $y$ values, calculate the error in that average, then calculate the $x$ value and it's uncertainties that way. You'll get the exact same value for the average $x$, but the error in $x$ won't be underestimated. In equations:
\begin{align}
y_{\mathrm{ave}} & = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i \\
\Delta y_{\mathrm{ave}} & = \frac{1}{N} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N (\Delta y_i)^2} \\
x_{\mathrm{ave}} & = by_{\mathrm{ave}} \\
\Delta x_{\mathrm{ave}} & = \sqrt{(y_{\mathrm{ave}} \Delta b)^2 + (b\Delta y_{\mathrm{ave}})^2}
\end{align}